# Isn't closure of a binary operator implied by it's definition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Consider, for example, a group $(G,\circ)$, where $\circ:G\times G\to G$. Then $\text{Im}\circ\subseteq G\implies \forall a,b\in G:\circ(a,b)\in G$, giving us the closure property. Is this true? If yes, why in all group like structures asks for closure if it is implied by the operator? Where have I gone wrong, if anywhere?

Comment: The statement $\circ: G\times G\rightarrow G$ is equivalent to the closure axiom. Do you know of references that list both? Also, for pedagogical reasons, the closure axiom is nice to state for when one defines a subgroup.

Comment: It is explicitly required when you are in the process of defining $\circ$. A particular case that is very common is when $\circ$ is being defined by restriction to a subset: $\circ=\overline{\circ}|_{G\times G}$ where $\overline{\circ}:\overline{G}\times \overline{G}\to \overline{G}$, and $G\subset \overline{G}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does seem strange to those of us following the practice of typing functions; if we say $\circ : G \times G \to G$ there is indeed nothing left to say.

However, there is an alternate practice that omits any notion of codomain. For those following this practice, the habit<sup>1</sup> is to simply specify "$\circ$ is a binary function on $G$", and the fact that $G$ contains all of the values of $\circ$ (when given elements of $G$ as arguments) is additional information that needs to be specified.

This may seem less strange to us if we consider a common situation mentioned in the comments; e.g. we may have some associative operation $\circ : X \times X \to X$ and some subset $G \subseteq X$, and we want to consider $(G, \circ)$ as a semigroup<sup>2</sup>. By restriction we've specified a binary ($X$-valued) operation, and we need to additionally insist that it is $G$-valued.

<sub>1: I do not really understand this practice, so I may be misrepresenting</sub>

<sub>2: Group structure has three components: the product,
the inverse and the unit! If you have a group and omit the inverse and unit,
 you merely have a semigroup with additional properties. It's a strange feature of groups that this omission doesn't really change anything.</sub>